# How to draw when holding down the mouse button?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create a simple painting application - it is just supposed to draw when you click and drag a cursor (just like Paint). I know I have to use `QPainter` but how can I handle it? How to do it? Any help would be really appreciated. I tried lurking through internet but didn't find too much info (I daw drawing lines etc. by code that you launch an app and it is here but I can not find an example of drawing something by user).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pretty broad question, but here are the basics:

1. Make a subclass of the `QWidget` class, so that you can override some of its virtual methods later on.
2. Create an object of your subclass and call `show()` on it (just before calling `QApplication::exec()`).  This object will appear on screen as a very simple window, and it will serve as your user's painting-surface.
3. Create a `QPixmap` object that you will use to store the bitmap that the user will draw.  Make sure to size the `QPixmap` to be at least as big as the maximum size of the window that you want to support.  Call `fill()` on the `QPixmap` to fill it with your favorite background color.
4. Override the `mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *)` method of your object to set a boolean is_mouse_down flag, and also to record the current position of the mouse pointer within the window (by calling `pos()` on the `QMouseEvent` object that gets passed in to the `mousePressEvent()` call and storing that into a member variable of your object).
5. Override the `mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *)` method so that if `is_mouse_down_is` set to `true`, it creates a `QPainter` object on the stack -- pass a pointer to the `QPixmap` to the `QPainter` object's constructor so that the `QPainter` will draw into your `QPixmap` object.  Then call `drawLine()` on the `QPainter` object to draw a line from the previous mouse position to your current one.  Finally, call `update()` to tell Qt to call `paintEvent()` for you ASAP.
6. Override the `mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *)` method to set `is_mouse_down` to false again
7. Override the `paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)` method to create a `QPainter` object on the stack -- pass a pointer to (`this`) to the `QPainter` object's constructor, so that it will paint onto the `QWidget` directly.  Then call drawPixmap() on the `QPainter` object so that it will draw your `QPixmap` object onto the widget's visible surface.

If you'd like to see a pre-written example, check out the Scribble application included with Qt, in `$QTDIR/examples/widgets/widgets/scribble`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I actually managed to do something like this: it was drawing a single pixel and this pixel was disappearing everytime. Now I know why and how to do it properly. Thank you for your time!!

Answer (score 5):

Here's Jeremy's answer in code instead of prose:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/simplepaint-39358392
#include <QtWidgets>

// Make a subclass of the QWidget class, so that you can override some of its 
// virtual methods
class PaintWidget : public QWidget {
    // Create a QPixmap object that you will use to store the bitmap 
    // that the user will draw [on].
    QPixmap m_pixmap;
    QPoint m_lastPos;
    // Override the paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) [...]
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override {
        QPainter painter{this};
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, m_pixmap);
    }
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *) override {
        // [...] size the QPixmap to be at least as big as the maximum size of the window
        // We'll also never let it shrink so as not to lose the already drawn image.
        auto newRect = m_pixmap.rect().united(rect());
        if (newRect == m_pixmap.rect()) return;
        QPixmap newPixmap{newRect.size()};
        QPainter painter{&newPixmap};
        painter.fillRect(newPixmap.rect(), Qt::white);
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, m_pixmap);
        m_pixmap = newPixmap;
    }
    // Override the mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *) [...]
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * ev) override {
        m_lastPos = ev->pos();
        draw(ev->pos());
    }
    // Override the mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *) [...]
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * ev) override {
        draw(ev->pos());
    }
    void draw(const QPoint & pos) {
        QPainter painter{&m_pixmap};
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
        painter.setPen({Qt::blue, 2.0});
        painter.drawLine(m_lastPos, pos);
        m_lastPos = pos;
        update();
    }
public:
    using QWidget::QWidget;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    QApplication app{argc, argv};
    // Create an object of your subclass and call show()
    PaintWidget ui;
    ui.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

It is not necessary to override the `mouseReleaseEvent`. In a widget, the default behavior is to track the mouse movement only when a mouse button is depressed. The `mouseMoveEvent` won't be called unless a button is depressed.

Comment: Thanks, I have managed and created my "simple paint" already. Appreciate it though.